# How to split kable over multiple columns?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to produce a "longitudinal" layout for long tables in RMarkdown with `kable`. For example, I would like a table to be split over two columns, like in the example below:

```
dd <- data.frame(state=state.abb, freq=1:50)
kable(list(state=dd[1:25,], state=dd[26:50,]))
```

However, this hack produces an output that looks a way worse than the normal `kable` output (for example the header is not in bold). Is there a "proper" way to do this using `kable`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`kable` is a great tool, but has limits.  For the type of table you're describing I would use one of two different tools depending on output wanted.

- `Hmisc::latex` for `.Rnw -> .tex -> .pdf`
- `htmlTable::htmlTable` for `.Rmd -> .md -> .html`

Here is an example of the latter:

```
dd <- data.frame(state=state.name, freq=1:50)
dd2 <- cbind(dd[1:25, ], dd[26:50, ])

library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(dd2,
          cgroup = c("Set 1:25", "Set 26:50"),
          n.cgroup = c(2, 2),
          rnames = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can still use Kable with a slight modification to your code.

```
dd <- data.frame(state=state.abb, freq=1:50)

knitr::kable(
  list(dd[1:25,], dd[26:50,]),
  caption = 'Two tables placed side by side.',
  booktabs = TRUE
)
```

This code is a modification of [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#multiple-tables-side-by-side). You can also find more information about tables on that page