# Print model in multi column using modelsummary in R

Tags: r, modelsummary

I like to print the output of `modelsummary` in a two-column format. When I do a regression interaction model with a factor variable with several levels, I get quite a few regression coefficients. The R console prints them side-by-side. My final output should be html for `r markdown` / `bookdown`.

```
interaction <- lm(mpg ~ factor(hp)*factor(am), data=mtcars)
interaction
```

[image]

When I do this in `modelsummary`

```
library(modelsummary)

modelsummary(title = 'Interaction Model.',
             list("MPG" = interaction), 
             gof_omit = 'R2|AIC|BIC|RMSE|Log.Lik.|F')
```

it's just too long.

[image]

Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `broom::tidy` and `dplyr::select` to get a 44 row table with 3 columns:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
interaction <- lm(mpg ~ factor(hp)*factor(am), data=mtcars)
tidy(interaction) %>% select(term, estimate, std.error)
```

`knitr::kable` can format the table if you need, and you can filter the rows, etc. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(knitr)
interaction <- lm(mpg ~ factor(hp)*factor(am), data=mtcars)
tidy(interaction) %>% 
  select(term, estimate, std.error) %>% 
  filter(! is.na(estimate)) %>% 
  kable(digits=3)
```

results in

| term | estimate | std.error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 29.65 | 2.296 |
| factor(hp)62 | -5.25 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)65 | 3.50 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)66 | -0.55 | 1.779 |
| factor(hp)91 | -4.40 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)93 | -7.60 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)95 | -6.85 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)97 | -8.15 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)105 | -11.55 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)109 | -9.00 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)110 | -8.25 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)113 | 0.00 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)123 | -11.15 | 2.516 |
| factor(hp)150 | -14.30 | 2.516 |
| factor(hp)175 | -10.70 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)180 | -13.35 | 2.445 |
| factor(hp)205 | -19.25 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)215 | -19.25 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)230 | -14.95 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)245 | -15.85 | 2.516 |
| factor(hp)264 | -14.60 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)335 | -15.40 | 2.054 |
| factor(am)1 | 0.75 | 1.779 |
| factor(hp)110:factor(am)1 | -1.15 | 2.516 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shape` argument. See the `?modelsummary` documentation and the *many* examples on the website.

```r
library(modelsummary)
interaction <- lm(mpg ~ factor(hp)*factor(am), data=mtcars)
modelsummary(interaction, shape = term ~ statistic)
```

|  | (1) / Est. | (1) / S.E. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 29.650 | 2.296 |
| factor(hp)62 | -5.250 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)65 | 3.500 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)66 | -0.550 | 1.779 |
| factor(hp)91 | -4.400 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)93 | -7.600 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)95 | -6.850 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)97 | -8.150 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)105 | -11.550 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)109 | -9.000 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)110 | -8.250 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)113 | 0.000 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)123 | -11.150 | 2.516 |
| factor(hp)150 | -14.300 | 2.516 |
| factor(hp)175 | -10.700 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)180 | -13.350 | 2.445 |
| factor(hp)205 | -19.250 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)215 | -19.250 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)230 | -14.950 | 2.717 |
| factor(hp)245 | -15.850 | 2.516 |
| factor(hp)264 | -14.600 | 2.054 |
| factor(hp)335 | -15.400 | 2.054 |
| factor(am)1 | 0.750 | 1.779 |
| factor(hp)110 × factor(am)1 | -1.150 | 2.516 |
| :—————————- | ———–: | ———–: |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |  |
| R2 | 0.985 |  |
| R2 Adj. | 0.942 |  |
| AIC | 120.3 |  |
| BIC | 157.0 |  |
| Log.Lik. | -35.168 |  |
| RMSE | 0.73 |  |

Comment: But there is no real multi-column output right? Even after outsourcing every second row (the SE), the list of coef is still too long. My format would allow for 2 to 3 columns (with diagnostics in the last column).

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

building on James_D's answer, here's a way to reshape the long table into a wide columns-of-columns format (using an eclectic mix of base R and tidyverse pieces):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
library(knitr)

parts = 3 ## multi-column parts to display alongside

tidy(interaction) |>
  select(term, coefficient = estimate) |>
  mutate(part = rep(1:parts, each = ceiling(n()/parts), length.out = n()),
         row_index = rep(1:ceiling(n()/parts), length.out = n())
         ) |>
  split(~ part) |>
  Reduce(f = \(x, y) x |> select(-part) |> left_join(y, by = 'row_index')) |>
  select(-c(row_index, part)) |>
  kable()
```

```
|term.x        | coefficient.x|term.y                   | coefficient.y|term                      | coefficient|
|:-------------|-------------:|:------------------------|-------------:|:-------------------------|-----------:|
|(Intercept)   |         29.65|factor(hp)180            |        -13.35|factor(hp)105:factor(am)1 |          NA|
|factor(hp)62  |         -5.25|factor(hp)205            |        -19.25|factor(hp)109:factor(am)1 |          NA|
|factor(hp)65  |          3.50|factor(hp)215            |        -19.25|factor(hp)110:factor(am)1 |       -1.15|
|factor(hp)66  |         -0.55|factor(hp)230            |        -14.95|factor(hp)113:factor(am)1 |          NA|
|factor(hp)91  |         -4.40|factor(hp)245            |        -15.85|factor(hp)123:factor(am)1 |          NA|
## [...]
```

You can polish up above output with {htmlTables} as described [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984289/how-to-split-kable-over-multiple-columns).